# Extract inner from a span element in selenium/protractor javascript

Tags: javascript, selenium, asynchronous, protractor

I have a span element on my page. I was wondering how I could extract the text in between the span opening tag and span closing tag. I'm using selenium with protractor in javascript.

```
<span....>
Inner text
</span>
```

Answer (score 13):

It is actually called *a text of an element*. Use [`getText()`](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=webdriver.WebElement.prototype.getText):

```
var elm = element(by.id("myid"));
expect(elm.getText()).toEqual("My Text");
```

Note that `getText()` as many other methods in protractor returns a promise. `expect()` "knows" how to resolve the promise - it would wait until the real text value would be retrieved and only then perform an assertion.

If you want to see an actual text value on the console, resolve the promise with `then()`:

```
elm.getText().then(function (text) {
    console.log(text);
});
```

Comment: When I do that, I get an undefined return value. Although I noticed the inner text of my span element is more like "\n
   text"

Answer (score 1):

To find elements on a web page, Protractor uses locators. Read up on them here: https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/locators.md
Since you haven't posted any code, this may differ from the solution you need. The locator I'll use is by using its ID.

```
var foo = element(by.id('yourspanID')).getText();
```